# How to parse CSV from file with PapaParse?

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I can't find a single bit of information about how to do this, so I'm resorting to asking a question here.

How do I actually load a local file and parse it using PapaParse?

I currently have:

```
$(function() {
    Papa.parse(new File("text.csv"), {
        complete: function(results) 
            console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        }
    });
});
```

...but I have decided the constructor must be intended for creating new files. How am I supposed to do this? PapaParse's [website](http://papaparse.com/) shows this:

```
Papa.parse(file, {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
    }
});
```

...buuut that doesn't explain where `file` came from.

Comment: the docs http://papaparse.com/docs#local-files say its looking for a File object from the DOM, ie. a File API object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: @haxxxton Thanks, I saw that, but I have not been able to figure out how you make/get a File object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the file from the system before trying to parse it.

If you are trying this in a web application, you could add a file uploader and call Papa.parse() after an event: i.e. either when file changes, or at the click of a button.

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

Then you need to add an `onchange` or `onclick` event function accordingly.

Inside the event function, you can access the file as:

```
event.target.files[0]
```

If you are using this on a server, you can use any filesystem methods to read your file.

Like in Node.js we have `fs.readFile()` function to read a file from the system at a given path.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think my confusion was that I forgot JS couldn't natively read files straight from the filesystem. I was trying to make a simple tool to aid my work. I've found [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), and it seems pretty easy to use, so I'll see what I can achieve with that :)